# Has the Lambeau Leap been banned at all NFL stadiums except Lambeau Field?

Tags: rules, american-football, nfl

The [Lambeau Leap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambeau_Field#The_.22Lambeau_Leap.22) is a celebration started by Green Bay Packers players who leap into the stands after scoring a touchdown at Lambeau Field.  The celebration has spread across the NFL though, because I've seen players on other teams leap into the stands after scoring a touchdown at their home stadiums.

During the September 28, 2017 game between the Bears and Packers at Lambeau Field, Green Bay running back Aaron Jones scored a touchdown in the second quarter.  He celebrated by doing a Lambeau Leap.  Jim Nantz and Tony Romo commented on the Lambeau Leap during the CBS broadcast, and they said that the Lambeau Leap had been banned at every stadium except Lambeau Field, where it had been grandfathered in:

> **Nantz**: First and goal at the 2.  Aaron Jones, he's in for the touchdown.  Running right behind Jahri Evans.  And there is your first career Lambeau Leap, Aaron Jones.
>   **Romo**: Just a normal handoff, and a really good jump cut right there by Jones getting in the end zone, and you see that right there, right behind Evans, and then he does the Lambeau Leap.  By the way, have you noticed Jim?  The Lambeau Leap?
>   **Nantz**: It's been outlawed everywhere...
>   **Romo**: No, no.
>   **Nantz**: ...but one place.
>   **Romo**: It's not outlawed here.
>   **Nantz**: It's grandfathered in here.
>   **Romo**: Grandfathered in, exactly.
>   **Nantz**: Everyplace but here.
>   **Romo**: It's like oh you know we like it, we're gonna keep it.
>   **Nantz**: You can't take that away.
>   **Romo**: No, it's too big a deal.

Is that true?  Has the Lambeau Leap been banned at every NFL stadium except Lambeau Field?  If so, when did that happen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the early 2000s, the NFL felt that touchdown celebrations had gotten out of control, delaying the game and promoting unsportsmanlike behavior.  Some of the top "offenders" included [Steve Smith](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkgMCPEP-0A) (who "diapered and wiped" the football), [Randy Moss](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dmqGg6Ccvw) (who mooned Packers fans at Lambeau) and [Chad Johnson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZVUSpLsUTds) (who put on a hall of fame jacket and proposed to a cheerleader).  So [in 2006](https://scout.com/nfl/Article/NFL-Rule-changes-for-2006-104343153), the NFL outlawed "excessive celebration."  Specifically, players were prohibited from any prolonged, excessive, or premeditated celebration, from using any type of prop while celebrating, from going to the ground during a celebration, and from engaging in a group celebration.

However, they clarified that the [Lambeau Leap would still be allowed](https://fansided.com/2015/01/11/lambeau-leap-isnt-penalty/), as long as it was one player only that jumped.*  Essentially, the Leap was grandfathered in as a celebration.  The goal post dunk was also grandfathered in at the time, but [in 2014](http://www.espn.com/blog/nflnation/post/_/id/122294/players-can-keep-leaping-at-lambeau) that was banned as well.

The 2006 celebration ban was not popular with the players or fans.  And many players and fans were upset that the Packers were the only ones with a celebration that was still allowed, while their players were prohibited from celebrating.

This year (2017), the NFL has made a rule change again; this time, it has [relaxed the excessive celebration rules](http://www.nfl.com/news/story/0ap3000000810537/article/nfl-relaxing-touchdown-celebration-rules-for-players).  Players are now once again allowed to use the football as a prop, to celebrate on the ground, and to engage in group demonstrations.  Offensive or prolonged celebrations, or demonstrations directed at an opponent, are still against the rules and will result in a penalty.

Before this year, it was debatable whether or not a Lambeau Leap-style celebration was within the rules at other stadiums.  Players have attempted it in other stadiums, and it is usually not flagged, as long as it follows all the other rules (no props, no groups).  With the new rule changes, a Lambeau Leap-style celebration should be allowed now in any stadium without question.

---

* Interesting side story: Several years ago I attended the annual "Packers Family Night" pre-pre-season scrimmage at Lambeau Field.  Although it was strictly a practice scrimmage, there were referees there, treating it as if it was a real game (for their own practice).  Early in the scrimmage, the offense scored, and the entire offense team did a Lambeau Leap.  The refs, of course, threw the flag for excessive celebration.

Comment: I would take [Alvin Kamara's TD celebration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gM8GRoCpMBE) during the Saints' win against the Redskins in Week 11 as proof that the Lambeau Leap is legal in other stadiums.  Not only did he do a Lambeau Leap after his TD, but he went completely into the stands and was not penalized.